# stringstream goes to failed state if line is not whitespace terminated

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to parse a file by reading it line-by-line and parsing each line using `stringstream`. Here's a simplified version of my code

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream f("input.txt", ios::in);
    stringstream ss;
    string line;
    while (getline(f, line)) {
        cout << "Got line `" << line << "'" << endl;
        ss.str(line);
        string prefix;
        ss >> prefix;
        cout << "Prefix: " << prefix << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In case of input.txt like (↲ used to denote newline)

```
a b↲
c d↲
e f↲
```

everything works as suggested, but for files like

```
a↲
c d↲
e f↲
```

stringstream goes to failed (not sure) state after `a↲` line. It seems that `stringstream` expects the line to be whitespace terminated or similar. Sure i could manualy add a whitespace or linebreak. Anyway, I failed to find any info about this behaviour in `stringstream` manual.

So my question is why is this happening and how to properly resolve this problem.

Comment: What do you expect the stream to do if there is no more input?

Comment: Oh, so it is just eof for stringstream. My bad, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `ss >> prefix` reaches the EOF character when there's only token to be extracted. You have to clear the flag with `ss.clear()`:

```
ss.clear();
ss.str(line);
```